# Hover color for entire row of the tree

Tags: java, tree, swt, selection, linewidth

I have a swt tree for which I have added SWT.EraseItem listener in order to get the selection, hover color for tree items. The selection, hover colors are appearing properly but that color is getting applied only till the text. I want it to get applied to the entire row.

Screenshot for your reference:
[image: Screenshot for your reference]

```
tree.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            if ((event.detail & SWT.SELECTED) != 0 && (event.detail & SWT.MouseHover) != 0) {

                int width = getBounds().width;
                GC gc = event.gc;
                gc.setForeground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 0, 0));
                gc.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 213, 215, 219));
                gc.fillRectangle(0, event.y, width, event.height);

                event.detail &= ~SWT.MouseHover;
                event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
            }
            if ((event.detail & SWT.SELECTED) != 0 && !tree.isFocusControl()) {
                int width = tree.getClientArea().width;
                GC gc = event.gc;
                gc.setForeground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 0, 0));
                gc.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 230, 232, 235));
                gc.fillRectangle(0, event.y, width, event.height);
                event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
            }
            if ((event.detail & SWT.MouseHover) != 0) {
                int width = tree.getClientArea().width;
                GC gc = event.gc;
                gc.setForeground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 0, 0));
                gc.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 213, 215, 219));
                gc.fillRectangle(0, event.y, width, event.height);
                event.detail &= ~SWT.MouseHover;
            }

            if ((event.detail & SWT.SELECTED) != 0) {
                int width = tree.getClientArea().width;
                GC gc = event.gc;
                gc.setForeground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 0, 0));
                gc.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 192, 235, 237));
                gc.fillRectangle(0, event.y, width, event.height);
                event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
            }

            Color previousForegroundColor = event.gc.getForeground();
            event.gc.setForeground(previousForegroundColor);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the problem. Do you mean the extending all the way to the right? The EraseItem event should have the bounds set to the full width of the column. Show us your code.

Comment: yes, i want this hover color to be extended towards right to cover whole tree
I have added the code above, please have a look

Comment: What is `getBounds()`? Why is that different from the other tests? On a quick test it doesn't look like the macOS tree generates MouseHover events on trees so I can't really test this.

Comment: any other way to achieve hover color for whole row of the tree
can you provide code

Comment: Note: `SWT.MouseHover` is actually an event id, not a value in the details field. You should be using `SWT.HOT` - they have the same numeric value so it won't change the way the code works, but you should use the correct value. Since I only use macOS which doesn't seem to generate HOT events for trees I can't test or suggest anything.